# Select Row on Rightclick JavaFX TableView

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm having a table view and I have added a context menu to that. When I right first time it highlight the row and show the context menu. But when I right click again on some other row it show the menu but doesn't highlight the new row and clear the old selected row.
**How can I clear the old selected row and highlight the new row ?**

I added the context menu using `setRowFactorymethod`

```
 mytblView.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<Rowdata>, TableRow<Rowdata>>() {
            @Override
            public TableRow<Rowdata> call(TableView<Rowdata> tableView) {
                final TableRow<Rowdata> row = new TableRow<>();
                final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
                final MenuItem mnuItemAnalyze = new MenuItem("Analyze");
                mnuItemAnalyze.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                        //logic for menu item
                    }
                });
                contextMenu.getItems().add(mnuItemAnalyze);
                // Set context menu on row, but use a binding to make it only show for non-empty rows:  
                row.contextMenuProperty().bind(Bindings.when(row.emptyProperty()).then((ContextMenu) null).otherwise(contextMenu));
                return row;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: hmm .. can't reproduce in jdk8u20: right clicking always selects the row before showing the contextMenu

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks anyway for your time. I was able to fix that by adding eventlistner rather than using setRowFactory

Comment: I can't reproduce either, but you could try `contextMenu.setOnShowing(event -> mytblView.getSelectionModel().select(row.getItem()));` (If you use an event handler instead of the custom table row, you have no guaranteed way of getting the correct item for the row on which the user clicked.)

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne this may be a bug with JavaFX/Swing integrations. I am experiencing this when I go from focus of a Swing node, to focusing on a JavaFX node. If I still have focus on a Swing Node, the described ContextMenu issue happens. If I click inside of the JavaFX node, the context menu operates fine.